# Reindexing provides values instead of NaN for missing values

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, missing-data, reindex

I want to complete my time serie of % humidity with missing records (or rows). Sensors are designed to record a mean value each 15min, so that is my target frequency. Here an example for one station (not the best in terms of gaps...) but I have 36 stations of measurements, 6 parameters and more than 24 000 records each to homogenize.

I choose columns of datetime and % humidity for example :

```
humdt = data["la-salade"][["datetime","humidite"]]

               datetime  humidite
0   2019-07-09 08:30:00        87
1   2019-07-09 11:00:00        87
2   2019-07-09 17:30:00        82
3   2019-07-09 23:30:00        80
4   2019-07-11 06:15:00        79
5   2019-07-19 14:30:00        39
```

I set datetime as an index : (so far it works)

```
humdt["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(humdt["datetime"])
humdt = humdt.set_index("datetime",drop=True)

                     humidite
datetime
2019-07-09 08:30:00        87
2019-07-09 11:00:00        87
2019-07-09 17:30:00        82
2019-07-09 23:30:00        80
2019-07-11 06:15:00        79
2019-07-19 14:30:00        39
```

Beside this, I prepare a datetime range matching my expectations (15min frequency) :

```
date_rng = pd.period_range(start=debut, end=fin, freq='15min').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
date_rng = pd.DataFrame(date_rng)
date_rng.columns = ["datetime"]
```

Then, I use this range to reindex my humidity values (expecting NaN when missing) :

```
humdt = humdt.reindex(pd.DatetimeIndex(date_rng["datetime"]))

                     humidite
datetime
2019-07-09 08:30:00      87.0
2019-07-09 08:45:00      88.0
2019-07-09 09:00:00      88.0
2019-07-09 09:15:00      88.0
2019-07-09 09:30:00      89.0
2019-07-09 09:45:00      89.0
2019-07-09 10:00:00      88.0
2019-07-09 10:15:00      88.0
2019-07-09 10:30:00      88.0
2019-07-09 10:45:00      88.0
2019-07-09 11:00:00      87.0
```

As a result, I get values of humidity from nowhere... not even a classical linear interpolation (ex : between 87% at 08H30 and 87% at 11H00). Please, help me, I have no clue what is going on... (also tried to merge and resampling, as here behavior is not as expected). Thank you !

Comment: Cannot reproduce... after removing all the back and forth between strings and Datetime values, the reindex give NaN for all new timestamps.

Comment: Thanks for trying Serge ! I also get this issue (all to NaN) doing a merge between expected datetime and dataframe of values.

Answer (score 1):

You can add attribute `fill_value` to df.reindex.

```
humdt = humdt.reindex(pd.DatetimeIndex(date_rng["datetime"]), fill_value=np.nan)
```

This will fill new values with NaN

Comment: Thank you Abbas. I tried with fill_value=np.nan (thought it was the default attribute but always better to verify it !)  but I get the same result                        
 `>>> humdt = humdt.reindex(pd.DatetimeIndex(date_rng["datetime"]), fill_value=np.nan)
>>>
>>>
>>> humdt
                     humidite
datetime
2019-07-09 08:30:00      87.0
2019-07-09 08:45:00      88.0
2019-07-09 09:00:00      88.0
2019-07-09 09:15:00      88.0
2019-07-09 09:30:00      89.0
2019-07-09 09:45:00      89.0
2019-07-09 10:00:00      88.0
2019-07-09 10:15:00      88.0`

Comment: That means it’s not adding values. They already exist somewhere in your dataset.

Comment: OK thank you for your help. I'm confused because I create this sub dataframe in order to work on only two columns, datatime and one parameter. I don't catch what are these data about... I need to obtain a dataframe with a consistent frequency, recorded values and NaN elsewhere but definitively no methods are working. I miss something.